# Организация сортировки записей в MySQL

Tags: php, сортировка, mysql

Проблема в следующем: необходимо сделать ручную сортировку записей. Cкриншот:

[image]

Трудность возникает при сохранении, а именно, не совсем понимаю, как организовать сохранение указанной сортировки. Отсюда и вопрос: как сохранить указанную сортировку в mysql?

Answer (score 3):

1. Добавить в таблицу поле `sort_order`, сохранять в него эти значения
2. При выборке - `ORDER BY sort_order`

Comment: Поле есть, а вот с сохранением этих значений туго :(

Comment: Значит, читать учебники самого начального уровня.